# How to design with DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, schema

I need to design a specific schema using DynamoDB, but I'm stuck.
I don't understand how it's working...
What I need is to re-create this schema with 1 or 2 class in DynamoDB and without Index.

Is it possible?
Thanks ! Bests !

[image: my_schema]

Comment: Looks like you want to create a relational database? Why go for Dynamo then?

Comment: I get my relational database, which is pretty easy but I need to make it with Dynamo, and now I just created a table with everything I need inside. But if I have 2 revisions for 1 page, and I want to select the latest version idk how to do it...

Comment: how can you create a thing without index ?? DynamoDB is all about indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the worst things I see is people taking an existing relational schema and shoehorn it into a NoSQL database. I say this as you need to be modeling for your application's access patterns, not for 3rd normal form. It takes a mindset shift for most people.

So to answer your question and help you solve your problem, you need to think about this problem a bit differently, start over to a point and gather more information about your workloads. Here are the initial questions I ask when I help people do schema design for NoSQL databases and ones you should be asking and trying to answer:

1. What data does the application need and when in the application's workflow?
2. What are the "hot paths" of your application that you need to optimize for?

For more information on this, and it covers these and other questions for you to plan this, I recommend you read these three pages from the DynamoDB docs:

1. [Relational Modeling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-relational-modeling.html)
2. [Relational Modeling First Steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql.html)
3. [Relational Modeling Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html)